# Pushed vector value keeps changing after conditional statement (C++)

Tags: c++

Sorry guys, I have to ask this again. I found another thread discussion on this stuff but the poster's example is way too messy, I can't understand their talk at all.

I want to read each character from a string and push those characters one-by-one into a vector. So far, I can do that all. Except, when a conditional statement gets executed before a push the rest of the values change.

For example, if it reads a string "ABC,DEF" it will return on the console screen, "A B C   ." but it will return "A B C , D E F" if there is no conditional statement.

```
    std::string temporarydata; std::vector<char> datarow;
    std::ifstream inputdata (filename.c_str());

    if(inputdata.is_open())
    {
      while(getline(inputdata,temporarydata))
      {

        for(int it2=0; it2<temporarydata.length(); it2++)
        { 

          if (temporarydata[it2] != ',')
          {
            datarow.push_back(temporarydata[it2]);
            std::cout << "Temp " << it2 << " is " << temporarydata[it2] << "\n";
            std::cout << "Data Rows " << it2 << " is " << datarow[it2] << "\n";


          }
        }
      }
    }
```

What should I do?

[this is the link to the rest of the code](http://ideone.com/rhLTQC)

Comment: You are saying that with the if statement, once the comma has been reached, the remaining letters are not added to the vector?

Comment: What is your print statement?

Comment: I don't know whether they get added or not, but some random values get pushed after the comma.

Comment: Cannot duplicate: http://ideone.com/9VMnje

Comment: You may go out of bounds of datarow as it might not have as many elements as temporarydata. Run in debug mode and it might detect this.

Comment: but if I don't include the conditional statement, all values get pushed correctly. Only when I try to include conditional statement, after the conditional statement gets executed, rest of the values will go wild.

Comment: Yes because when it2 is 6, datarow only contains 5 elements. It is invalid to reference its 6th element.

Comment: @DessyRatnaAsri The bottom line is that you are a variable `it2` to index into the `datarow` vector.  The `it2` has absolutely no relationship to the `datarow` vector.  If you're going to access `datarow` use an index *based on datarow*, not on another vector.

Answer (score 3):

You are reading past the end of your `vector`.  At index 3, you skip the print statement, and `datarow` has 3 elements.  However, now `it2 == 3` on your next iteration, which means you are trying to read from `datarow[3]` on your next print statement, even though `datarow` only has 3 elements (at indexes 0, 1, and 2).  As such, you are printing garbage.  You should invoke the print statement after the loop is finished or use `datarow.back()` (As suggested by Neil Kirk) instead of your loop control variable.